# synonyms() error in wordnet

Tags: java, r, wordnet

I want  to use  synonyms () described in 'Intro to the tm package' for R. It uses the wordnet package. The wordnet package downloaded from CRAN does not have Dict (dictionary) in its directory. I downloaded it from the Princeton site and copied it over to the directory. After using `sys.setenv()` and `setDict()` for setting paths, I still get this error:

```
Error in sort(unique(unlist(lapply(synsets, getWord)))) 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'sort': Error in unique(unlist(lapply(synsets, getWord))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'unique': Error in .jcall(synset, "Ljava/util/List;", "getWord") : 
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "t"
```

when I try `synonyms("company", pos = "NOUN")` or another English word in place of 'company'. The problem is in `getSynonyms()` called from `synonyms()`. Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Different combinations lead to different input string NumberFormatException. My Java is version 1.8.   I tried all the online resources. I added two paths to PATH for R's bin and RJava's jri. Discussion on the exception indicates it is a string to numeric conversion issue. I have made sure that Java to R linkage (via rJava) works (URL: https://www.rforge.net/rJava/ ).

Comment: Hi, It is now working. I used the .exe file at this URL: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/ . After that, once it is installed, I have to use these two in R: Sys.setenv(WNHOME = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WordNet\\2.1") and setDict("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WordNet\\2.1\\dict"), before calling library("wordnet").

Comment: Hi, setDict() was not needed and it can only be called after library("wordnet"). Just checked with a clean copy. And that makes sense!